# How do I manipulate input from the keyboard in Win32?

Tags: c++, winapi, input

Or to clarify this question, how can I make Windows think I hit a key, when I really didn't? I know I could possibly use SendMessage and specify the input there, but then wouldn't only my application receive it? I'd like control to the extent of all applications receiving the "fake" input. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `SendMessage` to whatever window you want, even on other processes. You can even use `HWND_BROADCAST` to send it to every to-level window on the system. But is that what you really want? If you're only interested in a specific program, you can get its window's handle using [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then send the message only to that window.

Note that if all you want to do is a simple keystrokes injection into another process, then `SendInput` is indeed the way to go. If you'd like to send some global keyboard shortcut it doesn't matter who has the focus. If you'd like to send the same input to more than one window using `SendInput`, you'll have to loop over the list of windows, and for each window first set the focus and then send the input.

Comment: As long as the input can reach the current application in focus I'm fine, therefor SendInput may be a better function to use in this case. Thanks!

Comment: SendInput is the safest way to go here. You can run into all sorts of unexpected issues using SendInput to fake input; it may work in some places, but fail mysteriously in others. (eg. input might actually be handled by another window; or the app may examine the keyboard state using GetKeyState, which SendInput doesn't affect, or the app may ignore input or act weird if it receives input when it doesn't have input focus.)

Answer (score 5):

What you describe, faking input, is implemented by the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Input goes to the thread which has input focus.

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks!